# Runtime errors: Linked list cannot be output correctly

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures

**Question**: Design a recursive algorithm to delete all nodes with value x in the singly linked list L without a leading node

**Problem**: The program cannot output a linked list correctly. And the problem is that I first created a singly-linked list with a head node, and then returned a singly-linked list without a head node to be deleted, but the deleted function DeleteX() cannot be output correctly after the execution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>      // Use malloc()
#define ElemType int

typedef struct LNode {
    ElemType data;
    struct LNode* next;
} LNode;

LNode* Init_List();
LNode *Create_From_Tail(LNode* L3);
void DeleteX(LNode* L4, ElemType x2);
void Print_List(LNode* L5);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LNode* L;
    ElemType x;
    L = Init_List();
    printf("Input a linklist end with -1: ");
    L = Create_From_Tail(L);
    printf("Input a being deleted data: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    DeleteX(L, x);
    printf("Output a linklist: ");
    Print_List(L);
    return 0;
}

LNode* Init_List()
{
    LNode* L2 = (LNode*)malloc(sizeof(LNode) * 1);
    L2->next = NULL;
    return L2;
}
LNode *Create_From_Tail(LNode* L3)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    LNode* r = L3;
    while (i != 0) {
        scanf_s("%d", &j);
        if (j != -1) {
            LNode* p = (LNode*)malloc(sizeof(LNode) * 1);
            p->data = j;
            r->next = p;
            r = p;
        }
        else {
            r->next = NULL;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return L3->next;
}
void DeleteX(LNode* L4, ElemType x2)
{
    LNode* s;
    if (L4 == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (L4->data == x2) {
        s = L4;
        L4 = L4->next;
        free(s);
        DeleteX(L4, x2);
    }
    else {
        L4 = L4->next;
        DeleteX(L4, x2);
    }
}
void Print_List(LNode* L5)
{
    while (L5 != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", L5->data);
        L5 = L5->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Begin by doing all the operations you need using pen and paper. Draw boxes for nodes, and arrows for links. Erase and redraw arrows as you perform your operations on the list. This is also useful to do while you're stepping through the code, statement by statement, in a debugger, as a visual aid to what's going on. I also recommend that you start using semantically relevant names instead of anonymous ones like `L4`. And you don't need numbers, remember that you could have the same variable name for different variables in different functions, and that includes arguments.

Comment: Another few general good tips: Try to separate things like input and operations. Do input in one function, which then calls a second function that adds to the list (and only adds to the list). And start *very* simple, really only an empty `main` function. Then build (with extra warnings enabled, that you treat as errors) and test. When all is working, then add a very small and simple piece of code, build and test. And so on, until you have all the code working. If there's a problem, then this will make it easier to pinpoint and debug the issue.

Comment: Also, turn on, read, understand and fix as necessary all warnings from your compiler. `DeleteX()`, for instance, is `void` but returns a value on certain paths.